# TcpClient keeps sending for a while even though there is no connection

Tags: c#, connection, send, tcpclient

**Background / Platform:**

.NET 4 / C#

I have a C# `TcpClient` that connects to a embedded device over Ethernet.
I am using two timers - one for storing the received data into a local `Queue<MyMessage>` and another for sending the data from another `Queue<MyMessage>` to the embedded device over TCP. Both of those run every `200 ms` and send/read whatever they have to send/read.

There is another timer that sends a keep-alive packet `every second` (currently only for debugging purposes).

**Scenario / Problem**

After establishing the connection, the embedded device starts sending some data to my `TcpClient`. This works as intended (see from the message log below). However, then I **turn off** the device (so it doesn't work at all). That means that it can't even close the TCP correctly. But that's ok. I want to test what happens if something like this happens in the real situation.

However, the TcpClient still keeps sending the data even though the server (device) is no longer online.

Here is the code for sending (using `NetworkStream.Write`):

```
while (messagesToSend.Count > 0)
{
    MyMessage msg = messagesToSend.Dequeue();
    clientStream.Write(msg.Data, 0, msg.Data.Length);

    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Sent: " + msg.MessageID);
}
```

Sending keeps going for another 45-50 seconds and then finally it breaks.
These are the options set for the TcpClient and NetworkStream

```
client.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 0);
client.NoDelay = true;
client.SendTimeout = 3000;
clientStream.WriteTimeout = 3000;
```

And here is the debug output:

```
16:32:02 Connecting
16:32:02 Authorizing
16:32:02 Sent: 255
16:32:02 Sent: 0
16:32:02 Authorized
16:32:02 Connected
16:32:02 Received: 255
16:32:02 Received: 226
...
... some regular communication here
...
16:32:06 Received: 251
16:32:06 Sent: 0
16:32:07 Received: 251
16:32:07 Sent: 0            // At this point I have turned off the device
16:32:08 Sent: 0
16:32:09 Sent: 0
...
... every second the same message
...
16:32:54 Sent: 0
16:32:55 Sent: 0
16:32:56 Sent: 0
16:32:57 Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
16:32:57 CommunicationError
```

Why does it take so long for the connection to realize that it is closed? Shouldn't the `NetworkStream.Write` fail immediately if the host is not responding?

How to **detect** that the power to the device was severed, and that a connection is no longer valid?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. How would you detect this if there's a switch/router between you? Your computer is still fully connected.

TCP/IP works this way. There's a few resends (usually with increasing timeouts) of any packet that is not confirmed by the recipient. The timeout values, and number of resends, are implementation specific to your tcp stack/operating system.

The [TcpClient.SendTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.sendtimeout.aspx) property only controls the time it takes to send the data further down the stream.

> After you call the Write method, the underlying Socket returns the number of bytes actually sent to the host. The SendTimeout property determines the amount of time a TcpClient will wait before receiving the number of bytes returned. If the time-out expires before the Send method successfully completes, TcpClient will throw a SocketException. There is no time-out by default.

Comment: So basically, the only way to know if a connection is still valid is that the server (device in my case) sends me some custom-protocol message every XY seconds, and then if I don't receive it for a XY (or a little more) seconds I know that something went wrong? I know that the Read operation would return 0 (as 0 bytes have been received) when the connection fails, but it seems it works only on Read, not on Write.

Comment: Not really. Packets can still be buffered somewhere between there and here. The only thing you can measure is the rtt (round-trip time). If you actually want to build something you're describing, switch to udp which doesn't implement resends (among other things).